# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ceyedev/.aws' while running docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying `sudo docker-compose up` on the below docker-compose file but it throws some errors. I am unable to get the reason. Everything is imported from images. Is there anything wrong with my docker-compose file or something with the system? I don't see the mentioned files/folders when I run `ls` in my home folder.
Here is the docker-compose file:

```
    ---
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    image: defectdojo/defectdojo-nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - uwsgi
    ports:
      - target: ${DD_PORT:-8080}
        published: ${DD_PORT:-9092}
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
  uwsgi:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.django
    image: defectdojo/defectdojo-django:${DJANGO_VERSION:-latest}
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    entrypoint: ['/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '-t', '30', '--', '/entrypoint-uwsgi.sh']
    environment:
      DD_DEBUG: 'False'
      DD_ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${DD_ALLOWED_HOSTS:-*}
      DD_DATABASE_URL: ${DD_DATABASE_URL:-mysql://defectdojo:defectdojo@mysql:3306/defectdojo}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_SECRET_KEY: ${DD_SECRET_KEY:-hhZCp@D28z!n@NED*yB!ROMt+WzsY*iq}
      DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY: ${DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY:-&91a*agLqesc*0DJ+2*bAbsUZfR*4nLw}
  celerybeat:
    image: defectdojo/defectdojo-django:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    entrypoint: ['/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '-t', '30', '--', '/entrypoint-celery-beat.sh']
    environment:
      DD_DATABASE_URL: ${DD_DATABASE_URL:-mysql://defectdojo:defectdojo@mysql:3306/defectdojo}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_SECRET_KEY: ${DD_SECRET_KEY:-hhZCp@D28z!n@NED*yB!ROMt+WzsY*iq}
      DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY: ${DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY:-&91a*agLqesc*0DJ+2*bAbsUZfR*4nLw}
  celeryworker:
    image: defectdojo/defectdojo-django:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    entrypoint: ['/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '-t', '30', '--', '/entrypoint-celery-worker.sh']
    environment:
      DD_DATABASE_URL: ${DD_DATABASE_URL:-mysql://defectdojo:defectdojo@mysql:3306/defectdojo}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD: ${DD_CELERY_BROKER_USER:-guest}
      DD_SECRET_KEY: ${DD_SECRET_KEY:-hhZCp@D28z!n@NED*yB!ROMt+WzsY*iq}
      DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY: ${DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY:-&91a*agLqesc*0DJ+2*bAbsUZfR*4nLw}
  initializer:
    image: defectdojo/defectdojo-django:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    entrypoint: ['/wait-for-it.sh', 'mysql:3306', '--', '/entrypoint-initializer.sh']
    environment:
      DD_DATABASE_URL: ${DD_DATABASE_URL:-mysql://defectdojo:defectdojo@mysql:3306/defectdojo}
      DD_ADMIN_USER: ${DD_ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      DD_ADMIN_MAIL: ${DD_ADMIN_USER:-admin@defectdojo.local}
      DD_ADMIN_FIRST_NAME: ${DD_ADMIN_FIRST_NAME:-Admin}
      DD_ADMIN_LAST_NAME: ${DD_ADMIN_LAST_NAME:-User}
      DD_INITIALIZE: ${DD_INITIALIZE:-true}
      DD_SECRET_KEY: ${DD_SECRET_KEY:-hhZCp@D28z!n@NED*yB!ROMt+WzsY*iq}
      DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY: ${DD_CREDENTIAL_AES_256_KEY:-&91a*agLqesc*0DJ+2*bAbsUZfR*4nLw}
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.27@sha256:540488d8f0e04c1077d17934d1c1511fe417e2221dff508ce4621f5efe6131db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      DD_DATABASE_URL: ${DD_DATABASE_URL:-mysql://defectdojo:defectdojo@mysql:3306/defectdojo}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DD_DATABASE_USER:-defectdojo}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DD_DATABASE_PASSWORD:-defectdojo}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DD_DATABASE_NAME:-defectdojo}
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    volumes:
       - defectdojo_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
       - 33062:3306
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.17@sha256:12202c13c8e1d7f5688e733e04f3713cf25c4478dde62be691e0a1d2c9346d1c
    restart: always
volumes:
  defectdojo_data: {}
```

Here is the error I am facing.

```
    Building nginx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/docker/471/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.25.5', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
    command()
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
    cli=native_builder,
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 548, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build, silent=silent, cli=cli)
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 367, in ensure_image_exists
    self.build(cli=cli)
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 1106, in build
    platform=self.platform,
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 160, in build
    path, exclude=exclude, dockerfile=dockerfile, gzip=gzip
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 30, in tar
    files=sorted(exclude_paths(root, exclude, dockerfile=dockerfile[0])),
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 49, in exclude_paths
    return set(pm.walk(root))
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
    for sub in rec_walk(cur):
  File "/snap/docker/471/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 184, in rec_walk
    for f in os.listdir(current_dir):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ceyedev/.aws'
```

**Update 1****
I ran the following commands and there was no repone. The terminal was ready for a new command:
`sudo chown -R $user:$user /home/ceyedev/.aws`
`sudo chown -R $user:$ceyedev /home/ceyedev/.aws` #where ceyedev is my username
After these commands, I tried `sudo docker-compose up` and and still the same error. Below are the permission details of the folder

```
ceyedev@ub18servertiny:~$ ls -l /home/ceyedev/.aws
total 8
-rw------- 1 ceyedev ceyedev  43 Sep 15 05:25 config
-rw------- 1 ceyedev ceyedev 116 Sep 15 05:25 credentials
```

Comment: I faced this similar issue in my docker file. I had to change the permissions of the permission denied file using chmod in the dockerfile RUN section. I didn't use docker-compose though.

Comment: @Simplecode I did not work much with docker. I just have that file. Any ideas on how should I try to get it resolved using the docker-compose? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the permission of the hidden file was not being changed. I changed the context directory and it worked well. I didn't get the reason why it did not work with hidden files but it worked in the new folder.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `.dockerignore` file with `data/` in it. It'll manage to rebuild without any issue.

`.dockerignore` can be placed within the build context directory(the directory that we specify at the end of a `docker build` command)

It's just like `.gitignore` for `git`

**Try this:**

I think it's due to the `/home/ceyedev/.aws/credentials` are under root permissions. You can change the permission to that user using the below command:

`sudo chown -R $user:$user /home/ceyedev/.aws`

***Note:*** Make sure you replace the `$user` if you want to change the permission to another user.

Comment: would you please mention where should I add that command? I am totally new to docker and facing that much complex docker-compose for the first time.

Comment: It can be placed within the build context directory(the directory that we specify at the end of a docker build command)

Comment: thanks for mentioning that but I am still unable to understand how do I do that? As I stated earlier, I am new to docker, would you please show me in my docker-compose by editing it a bit or by mentioning the command I should run? thanks a lot

Comment: Added a new approach try this

Comment: I have made an update to the question. That command doesn't work

Comment: can you check what is the permission for that directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223261/discussion-between-ashok-and-jamshaid).

Comment: I had the problem due to a local volume I mounted on the same folder as the dockerfile. Adding the volume folder to .dockerignore solved it. It makes total sense since docker was trying to copy the contents of the volume