# docker-compose permission denied error in hidden folder

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

docker-compose runs for the yml file in `/home/mac` as follows:

```
docker-compose -f /home/mac/vscode.yml build
```

however gives a permission denied error within `/home/mac/.config/` folder:

```
docker-compose -f /home/mac/.config/vscode.yml build
```

Error is:

```
ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/mac/.config/vscode.yml'
```

There seems to be a similar problem to what [Jamshaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11877320/jamshaid) stated below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64585125/393171

So I have given `777` permission to both `mac` and `.config` folders; but still doesn't work.

```
drwxrwxrwx 20 mac mac 4096 Oca 26 22:25 mac
drwxrwxrwx 23 mac mac 4096 Oca 26 22:26 .config
```

Another strange thing is that this works fine with `docker compose` command

```
docker compose -f /home/mac/.config/vscode.yml build

Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
```

But I need to make `docker-compose` run because Visual Studio Code uses `docker-compose`  in Dev Containers extention.

So may anyone help me figure out what kind of a problem is this? :)

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: What's the actual error?  Is Compose not starting up because it can't read the `vscode.yml` file, or is the problem actually coming from something like a `build:` block?

Comment: The error is: ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/mac/.config/vscode.yml'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries installing docker with apt and snap, solved the problem to some point; but at last stuck at the point where docker compose services don't communicate each other through the network and more permission errors.

The real problem seemed to be apt and snap installs was blocking each other.

So the solution is to uninstall docker both using apt and snap, then install as stated in:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

Don't follow the Docker desktop version. Install with apt repository.